# Apparently simple integral

Tags: integration

I am having trouble solving this apparently simple integral:

$\int\frac{x}{3+\sqrt{x}}dx$

Hints would be preferable than complete answer...

Thanks!

Comment: Perform a u-sub on the square root term. After that you will have to do long division. You answer will consist of some polynomial terms and a natural log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x = y^2$ and use long division to simplify the integrand.

Thus, we have $dx = 2 y dy$. Substituting in the original integrand, we have:

$$\int \frac{x}{3+\sqrt{x}} dx = \int \frac{y^2}{3+y} 2y dy$$

i.e.,

$$\int \frac{x}{3+\sqrt{x}} dx  = \int \frac{2y^3}{3+y} dy$$

Comment: Im stuck on long division. I now have:

$$\int y+(\frac{-3y}{3+y})$$

Comment: See edit. There seems to be some algebraic error in your work.

Comment: Managed it, thanks. Was tripping over simple things.